# UWP ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory

Tags: c#, file-io, uwp

I have the following code

```
private static async Task CreateZipFile(string folderPath)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folderPath, ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "backup.zip");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ;
        }
    });
}
```

In my UWP app. However I am getting access denied errors on the LocalFolder.
The directory I am trying to zip is in my LocalState folder so

```
folderPath = C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\MyApp_3y0bchp7kwvet\LocalState\BACKUP
```

Any ideas how to resolve? Other code has no problem accessing these folders.

Comment: if you are running this code from other package then it will now allow to read content from another app's local storage.  ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder points to LocalState folder only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd think the problem here is that you've used wrong path as *destinationArchiveFileName* in [ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485707(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

For a valid path, it should be `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\backup.zip"`.

Once you changed your code like the following, it should be able to work.

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folderPath, ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\backup.zip");
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Thanks very much for the answer.

Comment: This isn't a strictly UWP answer, as the ZipFile class is part of the .NET library, not the UWP library. It's only useful for those who are also working in C#, but wouldn't work for someone who is working in another language